# removeClass() is not getting applied 

Tags: jquery

in my jQuery code, `removeClass` is not working. Whenever I click `hide` link the `.close` element is not getting removed in IE6.0 but it works in firefox and IE8.0, Below is my jQuery code:

```
$(document.ready(function()){
    toggleNodes = function(node,action){
        var $componentone = $('.componentone', node);

        if (action == undefined || action == 'hide'))) {
            $componentone.addClass('closed');
            $componentone.hide();
        }
        else if  (action=='undefined'||action=='view'){
            $componentone.removeClass('closed');
            $componentone.show();
        }
    }
});
```

`close' is declared as below in .css file:

```
.componentone{
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border:0px solid #ddd;
}

.componentone.closed{
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border:0px solid #ddd; 
}
```

And in JSP I have used it like this:

```
<div="componentone">body of div</div>
<div="component">body of div new</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how your code is working anyhow. So much errors in there. Please clean up to present code which can work and make sure to include things as what `$info` really is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your else condition has a syntax error

```
else if { (action=='undefined'||action=='view')

        $info.removeClass('closed');
        $componentone.show();
       }

to

else if  (action=='undefined'||action=='view'){

        $info.removeClass('closed');
        $componentone.show();
       }
```